# Signing PDFs in linux

Tags: pdf, python, certificate

I'm trying to digitally **sign PDFs server-side**. So far I found that I can do this using MyPDFSigner, but it's far from my needs. Also I don't believe that this is the only option here.

**How to sign pdfs in linux?** Does Adobe provide any tool for server-side-signinig PDF documents (it does, see edit)?

It would be nice if it has python api, but command line tool will do too.

**EDIT:**
I found that its possible using **Adobe LiveCycle Digital Signatures ES2** which is **java appliaction**, but it comes with Adobe LiveCycle which is **quite expensive**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a portable java app that works from the CLI [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Security/PortableSigner-37712.shtml).  I haven't tried it, reversing Java is simple enough.  If you really needed a python version it should be possible to clone however it does it.

Credit to @seler on looking up the project page...It is open source.  Here's the [link](http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Nice. It shouldn't be difficult to rewrite it to python (if anyone needs it). And here is [project page](http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Bonus on actually looking for the project page.  Source available.  I just assume closed source a lot of the time ;)

Comment: FYI: we are now using PortableSigner in production environment. :)